# Displaying all groups on y-axis in highchats in R

Tags: r, highcharts

I would like to know how could I create a highchart chart that would contain all the observations for each id on y-axis for the dataset(df) like this:

```
id  time    value
1   6:00    1
1   12:00   0
1   18:00   0
1   0:00    1
2   6:00    1   
2   12:00   1
2   18:00   1
2   0:00    0
3   6:00    0
3   12:00   0
3   18:00   0
3   0:00    1
```

I am able to create a chart showing the observations for individual ids, but I would like to combine it.

The preferred result would be like this:

```
1| *                   *
2| *     *       *     
3|                     *
  6:00  12:00  18:00  0:00
```

Is there any way how to do this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi. You can use scatter series. Here you have a working javascript demo showing all used properties: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rb45awkj/ is this what you want to achieve in R? When it comes to your data... id is quite unintuitive, because, by definition, every element should have a different id.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was eventually able to create the required chat by assigning different values to each group, i.e. [id:1, value:1], [id:2, value;2]... After creating a column for each id I just added each of them as series to the chart.

Comment: Are you able to provide the code as answer so other users could easily learn from your example?

Answer (score 1):

I was eventually able to create the required chat by assigning different values to each group, i.e. [id:1, value:3], [id:2, value;2].

The original df:

```
id  time    value
1   6:00    1
1   12:00   0
1   18:00   0
1   0:00    1
2   6:00    1   
2   12:00   1
2   18:00   1
2   0:00    0
3   6:00    0
3   12:00   0
3   18:00   0
3   0:00    1
```

Since the id=1 was supposed to be on the top of the chart, I assigned the highest value to it and went down to the last id with the smallest value.

```
df$value <- ifelse(df$id == "1", 3, df$value)
df$value <- ifelse(df$id == "2", 2, df$value)
df$value <- ifelse(df$id == "3", 1, df$value)
```

The updated df:

```
1   6:00    3
1   12:00   0
1   18:00   0
1   0:00    3
2   6:00    2   
2   12:00   2
2   18:00   2
2   0:00    0
3   6:00    0
3   12:00   0
3   18:00   0
3   0:00    1
```

Each group could then its own column. The idea is to get each id in a separate column, so it could be easily added to the chart as a series. For this subsetting and merge could be used:

```
df_one <- subset(df, id == "1")
df_one <- select(df_one, time, value)
colnames(df_one) <- c("time", "value1")
df_two <- subset(df, id == "2")
df_two <- select(df_two, time, value)
colnames(df_one) <- c("time", "value2")
df_three <- subset(df, id == "3")
df_three <- select(df_three , time, value)
colnames(df_one) <- c("time", "value3")

df_final <- merge(df_one, df_two, by = "time", all.x = TRUE)
df_final <- merge(df_final, df_three, by = "time", all.x = TRUE)
```

The resulting final df looks like this:

```
time  value1  value2  value3
6:00    3       2       0
12:00   0       2       0
18:00   0       2       0
0:00    3       0       1
```

This could be then be added to a chart:

```
hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "scatter") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = df$time) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(df$value1),
                name = "Id: 1"
                ) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = c(df$value2),
                name = "Id: 2"
                ) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = c(df$value3),
                name = "Id: 3"
                ) %>%
hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
hc
```